# Deleting a single item from a list

Tags: python, list

so I'm trying to def Draw(n= int), but when i run this code, the command self.contents.remove(r), it only returns 1 item. and i need to remove the ball from the bucket while I'm drawing, so I won't get the same ball twice.

```
class Bucket:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.contents = []
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            for n in range(v):
                self.contents.append(k)

    def draw(self, n):
        x = []
        for ball in range(n):              
            r = random.choice(self.contents)
            x.append(r)
            self.contents.remove(r)
                
        if n > len(self.contents):
            return self.contents
        else: return x

h1 = Hat(red=3,blue=2)
print(h1.contents)
print(h1.draw(4))
```

the output is :

```
['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue']
['blue'] ---> this supposed to have 4 items.
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: `list.remove(r)` only removes the first matching element, not all of them.

Comment: You don't need `if r in list`. `random.choice()` will never return something that isn't in the list.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. You should not use Python keywords and built-in functions/types as variable names.

Comment: really? because my program is removing all of them with this line. also not using , list as a variable name , its just a example

Comment: The list has only 5 elements, and you're looping 5 times. You're going to remove everything from the list.

Comment: yes , i want to remove every element from "list" and make a new list  'x'

Comment: Then what's the problem? Each time through the loop you remove just one random element.

Comment: Why do you need the loop? Just do `x = list[:]` to make a copy of the list and `random.shuffle(x)`

Comment: okay let me explain, i have a list of balls, I'm defining a function, that draws a ball at random, and puts in other list , while I'm drawing i also want to remove from the list of balls, so i wont draw the same ball.

Comment: After making the new list, you can loop through that list and draw each ball.

Comment: If you want to stop short of drawing *all* of the balls, simply take the front slice after you `shuffle`.

Comment: I've edited the post, to be more clear

Comment: After the loop, `len(self.contents)` is `1` because you've removed 4 items. Since `4 > 1`, you return `self.contents` instead of returning `x`.

Comment: What's the intent of that `if/else` at the end?

Comment: hmm right , so i'll pass that first,  and YES! it worked. Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `if` test at the end. If you remove at least half the items from `self.contents`, then `n > len(self.contents)` will be true, and you'll return `self.contents` instead of `x`.

If you're trying to prevent an error from trying to draw more balls than are in `self.contents`, the `if` condition should be at the beginning of the function, not the end.

```
def draw(self, n):
    if n > len(self.contents):
        x = self.contents
        self.contents = []
    else:
        x = []
        for ball in range(n):              
            r = random.choice(self.contents)
            x.append(r)
            self.contents.remove(r)
            
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to remove an item from a list is just `list.remove(item)`.  I'm not sure why you are putting it in to a loop.

=== Edited after seeing comment by @barmar

So you either want

```
while item in list:
    list.remove(item)
```

or

```
list = [x for x in list if x != item]
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what he wants. He only wants to remove one element each time through the `for` loop, not all the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
balls = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red"]

new = []
for ball in range(len(balls)):
    r = random.choice(balls)
    new.append(r)
    balls.remove(r)
```

Comment: that's exactly what i did. but if you do that, and you return "new" , there will be only one element in the list

Comment: for me "new" equals ```['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue']``` now

Comment: why Am I not getting the same result? the code is absolutely the same..

Comment: I don't know, I checked mine multiple times and it works. Do you want to paste it here?

Comment: using this ``` before and after your code should be good :)